# Aggregation in Golang mgo for Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

Anybody knows what’s the equivalent of aggregate command we use in mongodb shell for golang mgo/bson?

Something like that:

```
aggregate([{$match:{my_id:ObjectId("543d171c5b2c1242fe0019")}},{$sort:{my_id:1, dateInfo:1, name:1}},{$group:{_id:"$my_id", lastEntry:{$max: "$dateInfo"},nm:{$last:"$name"}}}])
```

Comment: I can't write a full answer now but you can use the Pipe function from mgo, see http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Pipe

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming that `c` is your Collection:

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{"name":"John"}}})
resp := []bson.M{}
err := pipe.All(&resp)
if err != nil {
  //handle error
}
fmt.Println(resp) // simple print proving it's working
```

GoDoc references:

- [Collection.Pipe documentation](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Pipe)
- [Pipe and its methods](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Pipe)

Comment: how to get nested value from resp? i can get resp["someKey"], but not resp["someKey"]["someKeyKey"]

Comment: Are there anyway to count the total value of `pipe` instead of putting all of them into a slice?

Answer (score 2):

### Sample Code:

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"type": "stamp"}},
        bson.M{"$group": bson.M{"_id": "$userid",
            "count": bson.M{"$sum": "$noofsr"}}}})

resp := []bson.M{}
iter := pipe.Iter()
err = iter.All(&resp)
```

### Note:

**Please note that the line should end with (,) if you are not breaking in (,) it will throw error message even if your query is correct.**

### Output:

```
{
    "transactions": [
        {
            "_id": "three@four.com",
            "count": 10
        },
        {
            "_id": "one@two.com",
            "count": 12
        }
    ]
}
```